# Why does implicit conversion to constant iterator fail in this code?

Tags: c++, iterator, doubly-linked-list, const-iterator

This relates to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57718018/how-do-i-convert-iterator-to-const-iterator-in-my-custom-list-iterator-class/57718423?noredirect=1#comment101879758_57718423).

Here's a summary of that thread: I am trying to implement a doubly-linked-list class called `my_list` in C++, including iterators and I want automatic implicit conversion of iterator to const_iterator.

My original thought was to have something like

```
template<class T>
class my_list_iterator<T>
{
    node<T> pos_;
    /* code */
    operator my_list_iterator<const T>(){return my_list_iterator<const T>(pos_);}
};
```

and then inside `my_list` define `iterator` as `my_list_iterator<T>` and `const_iterator` as `my_list_iterator<const T>`.

However, as pointed out by Miled Budneck in the previous thread, this won't work because a pointer to `node<T>` cannot convert to a pointer to `node<const T>`. He suggested I re-implement the const iterator as a pointer to const node instead.

While that works, by looking around I also found one other possible way to define the iterator class:

```
template<class T, class Pointer, class Reference>
class my_list_iterator {
    node<T>* pos_;
    /* code */
    operator my_list_iterator<T,const Pointer,const Reference>() {return my_list_iterator<T,const Pointer,const Reference>(pos_);}
};
```

Then I can define `my_list<T>::iterator` as `my_list_iterator<T,T*,T&>` and `my_list<T>::const_iterator` as `my_list_iterator<T,const T*,const T&>`. I thought the last line would take care of the implicit conversion issue, but it seems to not be used at all.

For reference, here is the complete code:

```
template<class T> class node {
    node(const T& t = T()):data(t),next(0),prev(0) {}
    T data;
    node* next;
    node* prev;

    friend class my_list<T>;
    template<class U,class Pointer,class Reference> friend class my_list_iterator;
};

template<class T,class Pointer,class Reference> class my_list_iterator {
    public:
            // increment and decrement operators
            my_list_iterator operator++();
            my_list_iterator operator++(int);
            my_list_iterator operator--();
            my_list_iterator operator--(int);

            // bool comparison iterators
            bool operator==(const my_list_iterator& other) const {return pos_==other.pos_;}
            bool operator!=(const my_list_iterator& other) const {return pos_!=other.pos_;}

            // member access
            Reference operator*() const {return pos_->data;}
            Pointer operator->() const {return &(pos_->data);}

            // conversion to constant
            operator my_list_iterator<T,const Pointer,const Reference>() {return pos_;}

    private:
            node<T>* pos_;
            explicit my_list_iterator(node<T>* p=0):pos_(p) {}
            friend class my_list<T>;
};
```

and the error message in the end

```
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘my_list<int>::iterator’ {aka ‘my_list_iterator<int, int*, int&>’} to ‘const my_list_iterator<int, const int*, const int&>&’
```

So why does this code not work? Is there any small modification I can make to make it work, or is this design impossible to implement?

Comment: The real and expected template arguments don't match.

Comment: Can you expand on this?

Answer (score 0):

Given `Pointer = T*`, `const Pointer` is `T* const`, not `const T*`.  Type substitution is not like macro expansion.  `const Pointer` adds a *top-level* `const` to the type denoted by `Pointer`.  Similarly, `const Reference` is `T& const` (which is automatically adjusted to `T&` because top-level cv-qualifiers on references are ignored) instead of `const T&`.  (See [What is the difference between const int*, const int * const, and int const *?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1143262) for the difference between `T* const` and `const T*`.)

You need to use something like `const std::remove_pointer<Pointer>*` for this to work.